# module on test.pypi can't install dependencies, even though they exist

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi

I have done this small package that I want to distribute in my community. It is now on test.pypi and when I want to try to install it, it gives an error that dependencies couldn't be found.

setup.py

```
...
install_requires=[
    'defcon>=0.6.0',
    'fonttools>=3.31.0'
]
...
```

throws this error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement defcon>=0.6.0 (from sameWidther==0.6) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for defcon>=0.6.0 (from sameWidther==0.6)
```

but when I manually install, it works

```
pip install 'fonttools>=3.6.0'
pip install 'defcon>=0.6.0'
```

Comment: You have different Python interpreters installed. Verify the version with `python -V`

Comment: @TinNguyen yes I have more, using `pyenv` pip is linked correctly. The question is, why pip can't fand the dependencies, but can install them when I type the commands individually?

Comment: the `pip` you are referring to is used by another `python` interpreter. `python -m pip install 'fonttools>=3.6.0'`. Try to find the correct python interpreter `python -V`, `python3 -V`, `py -V`, `py3 -V`. Or call python using its full path. You can get the path of your current python with `where python` on windows and `which python` on linux

Comment: @TinNguyen all of the pips that I have can install both of those modules manually. You thought that running pip install on that module would invoke f.e. python2's pip and try to install those packages that are not available for python2? They actually are available for them and python2's pip installed them.

Comment: How do you pass TestPyPI index URL? You may be overriding the PyPI index.

Comment: @hoefling You are right, thanks! When I see `python -m pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ sameWidther==0.8 --verbose` tells exactly what you say. Could you answer the question on how to install the test properly? So others know too and I can share some small poins to you. I searched a lot, but didn't find any clue that this could be the case.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`-i URL`, or `--index-url URL` means "use URL for installing packages from exclusively". By passing `-i https://test.pypi.org/simple/`, you thus prohibit searching and downloading packages from PyPI (`https://pypi.org/simple`). To use both indexes, use `--extra-index-url`:

```
$ python -m pip install --extra-index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ sameWidther
```